# Reset row pointer of a mySQL result (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to loop through the results of a query a few times. After the first loop, I cannot go through the results again as the pointer is at the bottom. How can I make it return to the top? I dont want to run the query again as that is just going to use up more resources and return the same results.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers");
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute();

//This kind of loop will repeat elsewhere in the code
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){ 
//Do something here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){ 
    $rows[] = $row;  //use $rows later
    //Do something here with $row
}
```

Comment: Just saw duplicate.  Just use $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();